# HTTP/1.1 426 Upgrade Required on heroku

Tags: express, heroku, upgrade, http-1.1

I'm running a dyno for my Heroku ws and express server, but I have the response code 426 everytime I try to reach the express server. Event when I click on the "open app" to open in by browser, I have the same error message.

I'm running the client on Unity with UnityWebRequest and WebsocketSharp.
I tried to add request headers but none on the ones I tried (eveything that chatGPT told me) worked.
Surprysingly, the WebSocket is working perfectly.

I used to run heroku express before and everything was working, I changed nothin to my code.

Any ideas ?

Tried with all HTTP/REST, POST AND GET libs available on unity.
The problem also happens on web browser.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I opened my ws server in a route and removed the other express and it worked. Heroku allows only one server per dyno.